# Graphviz Separate Nodes

Tags: python, graph, graphviz, digraphs, pygraph

I have a Dataframe that links `Employee` to `Supervisor` and I am trying to create a `twopi` Graphviz to create a radial org chart. I am having issues where some of the nodes overlap. Here is my current code:

```
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import to_agraph

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='Supervisor', target='Employee',create_using=nx.DiGraph)

A = to_agraph(G)
A.graph_attr['splines']='curved'
A.graph_attr['ranksep']="4"
for node in A:
    # Style node to have color
    n = A.get_node(node)
    n.attr['style']='filled'
    n.attr['fillcolor'] = '#ab9beb'
A.layout('twopi')
A.draw('layouts/twopi.png')
```

Here is what the output looks like:
[image: Twopi graphviz layout]

What would be the best to show this without having the nodes of employee names overlap. Setting `nodesep` does not seem to affect anything

Comment: I know this issue, my feature request is that twopi can arrange text in a radial order, so long text points away/ towards the middle. Maybe you can add your support on my request (from a long time ago, don't remember where it is now) or go to graphviz and add this feature request. I will add my support on your request.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a "feature" of **twopi** - see the Graphviz gallery (https://graphviz.org/gallery/).   The documentation says **nodesep** works "differently" for **twopi**.
Maybe **neato** would work better - though **neato** needs fiddling with **mode** & **model** attributes.